# Find the rate of change of radius of cylinder with respect of time

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

**Question**:

A great amount of oil is spilled in the ocean. After a brief turbolence, the oil spreads forming a disk of radius $r$ and thickness $h$. The radius of the disk is increasing and the thickness is decreasing. Knowing that $h=\frac {c}{\sqrt t}$, prove that the $\frac {dr}{dt}  $ is inversely proportional to $t^{3/4} $.

**Attempted solution**:
We know that the volume of oil spilled ($V$) remains unchanged. Therefore:
$$\frac {dV}{dt} = \pi(r^2\frac{dh}{dt}+2rh\frac{dr}{dt}) = 0$$
$$\frac {dh}{dt} = \frac {-1}{2} \frac{c}{t^{3/2}}$$
Symplifying and substing:
$$ \frac {-1}{2} \frac{c}{t^{3/2}}r^2+2r\frac {c}{\sqrt t}\frac{dr}{dt} = 0 $$

Isolating the request:
$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac {1}{2} \frac{c}{t^{3/2}}r^2 * \frac {t^{1/2}}{c *2r}$$
$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac {1}{4} \frac{r}{t} $$

I think that the $r$ at the top is the problem, but I don't know how to go on. I've also tried with implicit differentiation and I get the same result.

Ps. Sorry for my bad English, which is obviously not my first language!

Answer (score 1):

Everything you've done is fine. But you haven't used $V_0 = \pi r^2 h$ to get $r$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: So I could have solved the whole problem saying: $$r = \sqrt{\frac{V_0}{\pi *c}}*t^{1/4} $$       and saying that $$\frac{dr}{dt} =  \sqrt{\frac{V_0}{\pi *c}}*(1/4)*t^{-3/4} $$ since $V_0$ and $c$ are constants?

Comment: Yes,  not a great related rates problem. Or solve for $r$ as a function of $h$ and then differentiate with respect to $t$ with the chain rule.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot anyway!